# Get saved file path without any postback

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, file-upload, postback

I want to be able to upload file and get the new saved path back, without any postback. I have already tried to use `updatepanel` BUT then the fileupload was found as null.

Practically I want to get the `File_Path_Text` in order to use it in a javascript method.

The follwoing is the code I am using;

```
 protected void get_path(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                FileUpload1.SaveAs(@"C:\temp\" + FileUpload1.FileName);
                File_Path_Text = @"C:\temp\" + FileUpload1.FileName;
            }
        }
```

The following is the asp part;

```
 <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" accept="kml"/>
 <asp:Button id="Button1" text="Add layer to map" OnClick="get_path" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the text to hidden field and make that hidden field server accessible. You can also use [public propert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548549/asp-net-how-do-i-access-a-property-of-my-usercontrol-from-within-jscript)y to assign value to it and access it on client.

*Html*

```
<input type="hidden" runat="serer" id="hdnText" />
```

*Code behind*

```
hdnText.Value = @"C:\temp\" + FileUpload1.FileName;
```

*Javascript*

```
 alert(document.getElementById("<%= hdnText.ClientID %>").value);
```

To upload file asynchronously you can use some jQuery plugin, like [Ajax File Upload](http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/AjaxFileUpload-Demo/)

Comment: But Am I right if i say that like this there will be still a postback?

Comment: I want to remove the postback but thnks for your post

Comment: You are welcome, you can use some jquery plugin like, http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/AjaxFileUpload-Demo/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Seems really good for my use but what i did not understand is how from the plugin can i get the filename being uploaded. @Adil

Comment: I am not sure about this plugin but you need to understand how jQuery async works, this is an example for using jQuery ajax with asp.net, http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Answer (score 1):

A very simple option is [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/). You can hook it up to an HttpHandler and have your uploads happen in the background while the application remains interactive.

UpdatePanels will give you trouble with uploading files.

Comment: Can you pls explain by hook it up to httphandler mean? Thnks @nunespascal

Comment: Uploadify takes a serverside script as an argument. This is best implemented as a HttpHandler and you should readily get the code for it by a simple search. By hook, I meant specify the url for your HttpHandler to accept the files on the server

Answer (score 0):

create a ashx file( http handler) and put the  below code(put your path)  there.

```
window.open('<%=Server.MapPath("~/path")%>')
```